# Apache reverse proxy for video streaming

Tags: php, apache, proxy, xampp, video-streaming

I am new to Apache.

I have a situation in which my server PC is connected to both WiFi as well as wired(Ethernet) network.

The situation is displayed in following image.(image is in pastebin)
[Mynetwork architecture](http://imagebin.ca/v/1zA9LKQ0xmwq)

I am able to watch HTTP stream from the IP camera in my server PC (same subnet).

But how can I create a webpage (hosted in my server PC) from which users from the userpc should be able to watch stream from the IP cameras.

Is it possible to use Apache reverse proxy to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this scenario deploying Apache as reverse proxy in server PC can solve the issue. Following steps need be done to setup Apache as reverse proxy:

- Enable mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http Apache modules
- Set 'ProxyPass' directive as below

  ProxyPass <Path-accessed-from-userPC> <URL-to-access-HTTP-stream-at-serverPC>